# How to get spring mvc controller model key value inside javascript?

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, jquery, spring-mvc

I am using a spring mvc controller. Inside controller i am putting some value lets say string inside model. Now i would like to retrive that value or lets just say print that value inside a javascript. How do i do it?
Here is my controller class. I am adding "movie" as key. Now i want to display that name of the movie inside java script (Not inside JSP. However Inside JavaScript)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/movie")
public class MovieController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMovie(@PathVariable String name, ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("movie", name);
        return "list";

    }

}
```

here is my JSP

```
<html>
<head>
//I want to print movie name inside java script not inside jSP body tag.
<script type="text/javascript">
var movie_name = ${movie};
alert("movies name"+ movie_name);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Movie Name : ${movie}</h3>//When i print here its working fine. 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this:

```
var movie_name = "${movie}";
```

instead of:

```
var movie_name = ${movie};
```

When using `${movie}`, the value gets placed on the page without quotes. Since I'm guessing it's a string, Javascript requires strings be surrounded by quotes.

If you checked your browser's console, you probably would've seen an error like `Unexpected identifier` or `___ is not defined`.

Comment: Lan i got a small question what if the  model.addAttribute("login", new Login("uname","pass")); have some object inside map and i want to print just one attribute of that object inside javascript. Like the object is of Login Class and it has username and password as attribute. Now i want to print just user name inside javascript. How do i do it? For example var login = "${SomeOject}"; alert(login.uname); ?? how do i get individual values of Login Class?

Comment: @DheerajVarne What is `SomeObject`? An `Object`? In your JSP, you can use `${movie.attribute}`, but it depends on how `SomeObject` is defined

Comment: @DheerajVarne In your specific `Login` example, you'd have to define a method in your `Login` class called "getUsername", and in your JSP, you'd use `${login.username}`. Note that it's all case sensitive

Comment: model.addAttribute("someObject", new Login("uname","pass")); //This is what i added in model key value attribute. Now i would like to print just uname inside javascript rather than printing all Login object.

Comment: @DheerajVarne Yes, so go back to your `Login` class. Add 2 new methods like this: `public String getUsername() { return this.username; }` and `public String getPassword() { return this.password; }`. Then, in your JSP, use this: `var username = "${login.username}";` and `var password = "${login.password}";

Comment: @lan Thanks yeah ${login.username} this worked. Its clear now. Its great help.

Comment: @lan Can i show same data in ajax $.ajax({ //give alert with userName inside ajax });

Comment: This doesn't work if the js file which contains such assignment is imported into the UI template.

Comment: @krm Of course, JS files aren't evaluated by Spring MVC. That requirement wasn't part of the OP anyways. I don't like this approach anyways - you shouldn't have to print server variables in JS - but I was just answering the OP

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

If you had added the object into the model as:

```
model.addAttribute("someObject", new Login("uname","pass"))
```

Then you get the properties of the model object as

```
var user_name = ${someObject.uname}; // This is assuming that the Login class has getter as getUname();
var user_pass = ${someObject.pass};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
jsp code ...

<script>

some js code ..
..
var formProperty = <c:out value="${fromBean.property}" />

</script>

..

</html>
```

This worked for me where formBean is the name of form backing object and property is filed of the form class