# cannot access list of object sent from modelmap in FTL file

Tags: java, javascript, html, spring, freemarker

Im new to ftl(FreeMarker template). I send a List of object from my controller using model map like this

### My controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/xxx")
public String myMethod(ModelMap model){
  List<MyDTO> dto = mymethods(); // I return some list objects in this method
  model.addAttribute("dto",dto);
  model.addAttribute("dtoLength",dto.size());
  return "myview"; 
}
```

### MyDTO.java

```
public class myDTO{
  Public String var1;
  Public String var2;

  public String getVar1() {
return var1;
  }
  public void setVar1(String var1) {
this.var1 = var1;
   }      
  public String getVar2() {
return var2;
  }
  public void setVar2(String var2) {
this.var2 = var2;
   } 
}
```

Now i try to access dto from my ftl's javascript.I tried it many ways like this:

```
 var dto=${dto};
```

it said whatever must be inside ${....} should be either string,integer,boolean ..blah blah

So i thought of iterating it like this to get what i want

```
var valueIWanted;
if(${dtoLength}>0){
  for(var i=0 ; i < ${dtoLength} ; i++){
     ticketList[i] = ${ticket[i].var2};
  }
}
```

but i was not able to access it this way too.what am i supposed to do in here ?I think i m missing the syntax.Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: where have you defined `ticketLength` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily access modelMap data as :

```
    <#list dto as dtoList>
    <tr>
        <td>${dtoList.var1}</td> <td>${dtoList.var1}</td>
    </tr>
    </#list>
```

You don't need to send the length of `DTO`, if you are using it for other purpose then you can use it.

and you can simply iterate list, you don't need `for` loop.

Look [this.](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-freemarker-ftl-example/)

If you want to access the data using the JavaScript then you can use ajax request on page load on controller and it sends you a response with data and then process that data and print on FTL page. If possible then use some JavaScript framework so to handle such a request become easy and convenient.

Still you can do : `var dtoList= "${dto}";`. not without quote.

See [SO Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206754/how-to-get-spring-mvc-controller-model-key-value-inside-javascript)

For to check empty or not :

```
[#if dto??]
   //inside it write all your code
[/#if]
```

You can check it [here.](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_quickstart_template.html)

With [example.](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing_test)

Comment: when i do it this way it throws me error like :  Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/myapp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> model  [in template "myFile.ftl" at line 19, column 16]

Comment: Hey friend !! I got it nw .. while i used just the dto instead of model["dto"].Thanx a lot !! :)

Comment: sure.But my next question is how to check if list is empty??

Comment: @user2078883  -I have updated the answer with to check empty or not.

Comment: Thanks bro.Helped a lot in ma project

Comment: Oh it's my pleasure.. Sharing is best.. Keep smiling.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try

var dto="${dto}";

instead of

var dto=${dto};

Comment: No..Its not working out either.The same error is thrown as said previously