# Copying one list to another with FTL file

Tags: java, freemarker

I am using FTL file as front end.
I need add objects into one list and check that list for empty.
How I need to add the list?

Answer (score 1):

You can check using following that list is empty or not ?

```
[#if dto??]
   //inside it write all your code
[/#if]
```

here `dto` is name of `list` send from your `controller`.

To iterate list :

```
    <#list dto as dtoList>
    <tr>
        <td>${dtoList.var1}</td> <td>${dtoList.var1}</td>
    </tr>
    </#list>
```

here `dto` is class that sent from `controller` and that have 2 fields: `var1` and `var2`.

Still Problem Post me.

look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219222/cannot-access-list-of-object-sent-from-modelmap-in-ftl-file/24219299#24219299)  my answer.

Comment: In your example, I want only some dto in dtoList based on some condition and how can get some dto using list

Comment: You can use `#assign` for that like `<#assign seasons = ["winter", "spring"]>`, you can put this in your condition.

Comment: `dto??` doesn't check if the list is empty. It checks if the list exists.

Answer (score 0):

To check if `myList` is empty:

```
[#if myList?size != 0]
   not empty
[#else]
   empty
[/#if]
```

To check if `myList` is empty or missing (`null`):

```
[#if dto?has_content]
   not empty
[#else]
   empty
[/#if]
```