# How to display the values coming from springboot controller in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I have a controller which is passing the json object wrapped inside a model.

```
@RequestMapping("/template")
public String showTemplate(Model model) {       
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("equipmentID", "30584D277D6D4568B17EBB8917D0CB15");
    model.addAttribute("template",obj);
    return "templates";
}
```

I would like to use these values in my javascript. I am not able to do that. However, I can see display these values in HTML.

```
<head>
<script>
    function test()
    {
    var temp = "${template}";
    alert(temp); // The values are not displayed here
    }
</script>
```

```
<body onload="test()">
    <span th:text="${template}"> </span> //I can display the values here        
<body>
```

I have also looked into this question [How to get spring mvc controller model key value inside javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206754/how-to-get-spring-mvc-controller-model-key-value-inside-javascript) and tried both the options with or without quotes with no success.

I have also tried defining in HTML:

```
        <input type="hidden" id="templates" value='${template}'/>
```

and using getElementById in my javascript with no success:

```
        var template = document.getElementById("templates");
```

Comment: I am struggling with the same problem bro... Have you solved this problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it has to do with the script's execution time. That is probably why you can display it on the `body` (meaning after page rendering) but not on the script.

So, what I would suggest is to have JS script as a separate file (e.g. `test.js`) and then include it in your HTML with the `defer` keyword (e.g. `<script src="/js/test.js" defer></script>`).

Using `defer` guarantees that the script is executed after page load (see [How to make JavaScript execute after page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/how-to-make-javascript-execute-after-page-load) for more details)

Answer (score -1):

Using thymeleaf inlining you can use the below:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
var message = [[${template}]];
alert(template);
</script>
```

There are additional ways to access server side variables depending on your use case refer to http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining for more information.